# error permission denied (publickey , keyboard-interactive) through ssh (scp) between linux

Tags: ssh, password, scp

I am connecting from bastion (server-name) to another server (ecash) through ssh via a key pair.

I have to copy a file called `htdocs` from ecash to bastion, so I am running:

```
scp source_user@source_remote_host:/usr/bin/mysql_backup.sh \
     target_user@target_remote_host:/var/tmp/
```

but that's asking me for a password, even though I was connected through a key pair.

And when I enter the password, I get permission denied error (publickey, keyboard-interactive).

Is there issue in the command or file permissions? What can I do?

Comment: As far as I can tell, with this syntax, `target_remote_host` will see an incoming connection from `source_remote_host` (which may not be what one expects). So I guess you don't have the neccessary private keys on `source_remote_host`? Maybe things will be better if you allow ssh agent forwarding on `source_remote_host`.

Comment: i want to copy folder htdocs from ecash-server under directory /var/www/localhost/htdocs                                                                                               to baston-server in any directory.                                                                                 please check my scp command is right ? or how will be                                               scp root@ecash-staging:/var/www/localhost/htdocs.  /home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this command that worked for me:

```
rsync -avp ssh --progress /home/ root@ecash-staging:/var/www/localhost/htdocs
```

Answer (score 2):

> but that's asking me for a password, even though I was connected through a key pair.

Using this syntax is connecting from the first host (not from your host) to the second. You can authenticate from your host using `-3` switch, which is usually more convenient:

```
scp -3 source_user@source_remote_host:/usr/bin/mysql_backup.sh \
    target_user@target_remote_host:/var/tmp/
```

Comment: Let's hope there never is a protocol version 3, and no protocol version 4 until IPv4 is deprecated. ;)

Comment: There will be SSH protocol 3, but it will probably not have this switch for `scp`.

Comment: i used this command that worked for me .                                                               rsync -avp ssh --progress /home/root@ecash-staging:/var/www/localhost/htdocs